# CSS: Canvases won't size correctly and won't layer

Tags: css, html5-canvas

So I'm having two kinds of canvas trouble.

***Trouble 1: canvases won't size correctly***

I'm trying to make a nice little stack of white boxes but they won't size themselves correctly to their div.

[image]

See how they extend too far past the bottom of the green rectangle? They're supposed to fit exactly inside the padding border. Why not they do??

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="behindAll">
    <div id="dotTextList">
        <canvas id="dotCanvas1" class="dotTextCanvas"></canvas>
        <canvas id="dotCanvas2" class="dotTextCanvas"></canvas>
        <canvas id="dotCanvas3" class="dotTextCanvas"></canvas>
        <canvas id="dotCanvas4" class="dotTextCanvas"></canvas>
        <canvas id="dotCanvas5" class="dotTextCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
#behindAll {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#dotTextList {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dotTextCanvas {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 20%;
  width:100%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

I've defined the little white boxes as 20% of their parent, so they should be playing nice, but they're not.

***Trouble 2: canvases won't layer***

And ultimately, I want to have the five white canvases draw themselves in front of a large background canvas.

Here's my HTML for that:

```
<div id="behindAll">
    <canvas id="backgroundCanvas" />
    <div id="dotTextList">
        <canvas id="dotCanvas1" class="dotTextCanvas"></canvas>
        <canvas id="dotCanvas2" class="dotTextCanvas"></canvas>
        <canvas id="dotCanvas3" class="dotTextCanvas"></canvas>
        <canvas id="dotCanvas4" class="dotTextCanvas"></canvas>
        <canvas id="dotCanvas5" class="dotTextCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#behindAll {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#backgroundCanvas {
  z-index: 5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#dotTextList {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dotTextCanvas {
  z-index: 9;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 20%;
  width:100%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

And here's the result:

[image]

The white boxes are gone!

I've switched around the order of things, I've tried z-indexes (as you can see), and I just can't seem to get those white boxes a) the right size and b) drawing in front of the blue box.

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is causing your problem in trouble2:

(remove this)
`<canvas id="backgroundCanvas" />`

sorry, please use this

```
<div id="behindAll">
    <canvas id="backgroundCanvas">
    <div id="dotTextList">
        <canvas id="dotCanvas1" class="dotTextCanvas"></canvas>
        <canvas id="dotCanvas2" class="dotTextCanvas"></canvas>
        <canvas id="dotCanvas3" class="dotTextCanvas"></canvas>
        <canvas id="dotCanvas4" class="dotTextCanvas"></canvas>
        <canvas id="dotCanvas5" class="dotTextCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    </canvas>
</div>
```

and this

```
#backgroundCanvas {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dotTextCanvas {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 20%;
  width:100%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

trouble1:

(set this)

```
.dotTextCanvas {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: calc((100% - 20px)/5);
}
```

Comment: Awesome help on trouble 1! As for trouble 2, maybe I stated my goals really badly. I want to keep that background canvas *and* the four white boxes, with the boxes drawn in front of the background canvas. Removing the canvas entirely solves the goal only in the most literal sense--in terms of what I'm trying to do, though, not so much. But your help on #1 is fantastic!

Comment: I said you to remove that tag because you wrote that incorrectly. Your that tag has no starting tag. I think you ```<canvas id="backgroundCanvas" />``` you put the ```/``` incorrectly. it should be ```<canvas id="backgroundCanvas">``` and ending tag ```</canvas id="backgroundCanvas">``` I think you get the idea

Comment: if you clarify that I'll check the thingy that makes this the answer

Comment: Wow that was phrased poorly by me. I meant if you explain in your answer more clearly how to fix it, like you did in your comment above, I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: I marked this as the answer, but it doesn't work for me when the dotTextList is wrapped in the backgroundCanvas. It does work when the ending canvas tag is added right after the declaration of the backgroundCanvas.